# Create a Delegate for iphone (in a separate file)

Tags: iphone, implementation, delegates, protocols, nsxmlparser

I have been looking for hours and didn't find anything so I decided to give up and ask for your precious knowledge ;)

In order to make my code cleaner, I would like to implement the delegate methods of NSXMLParser in another file ... but I couldn't find any tutorials ...

Could someone explain me briefly how to do that ?

Cheers mates,

Gauthier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Class that implements the methods you want your parser to respond to, then set the delegate of your NSXMLParser instance to an instance of your new Class.

Comment: As my delegate instance will not be retained by my parser, where am i supposed to release it ? In dealloc ? Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: One more question : what type is supposed to be my delegate class ?nsobject ?!? Or what ?

Cheers

Comment: Make the delegate class inherit from NSObject.

Comment: It's hard to say where you should release your delegate instance.  That depends on your code and a lot of things that are not easily answered in comments.  I suggest reading up on iPhone memory management.  But yeah, dealloc() is an option, but not necessarily the right option.

Comment: Ok, i think i got it ;) last thing i was thinking about is whether it was better to create a subclass of nsxmlparser (and set self as delegate) or to create a delegate ... Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: I think I can argue either way; depends on what you're doing.  If your delegate implements methods that would be useful in other instances of NSXMLParser, than it make sense to use a distinct delegate.  But, if you're just doing this once, and can never conceive of reusing these methods, then subclassing NSXMLParser would be just fine.  I would lean towards a separate delegate object since it's more flexible.